# Complexity of a variant of the Subset Sum Problem (second level polynomial hierarchy)

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard, complexity-classes

What is the complexity class of the following variant of the *SSP* problem:

**Input**: set of integers $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$, integer $k$ and integer $T$.

**Output**: *Yes*, if there exists a subset $S\subseteq \{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ for which: $|S|= k$ and $\forall S'\subseteq \overline{S}$ it holds that: $\sum_{x_i \in S}x_i + \sum_{y_i \in S'}y_i\neq T$

Clearly, the problem is in $\Sigma^P_2$, but how can we prove that the problem is also $\Sigma^P_2$-Hard? (if it is...)

A possible reduction maybe from the *Generalized-Subset Sum problem*, mentioned in [Umans Compendium](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Marcus-Schaefer-2/publication/2391755_Completeness_in_the_Polynomial_Time_Hierarchy/links/543ede710cf2e76f022447d4/Completeness-in-the-Polynomial-Time-Hierarchy.pdf), which is $\Sigma^P_2$-Hard and is defined as follows:

**Input**: two vectors $u$ and $v$ of integers, and an integer $T$.

**Output**: *Yes*, if $(\exists x) (\forall y) [ux+vy\neq T]$ is true, where $x$ and $y$ are binary vectors in the same length as $u$ and $v$.

Although the two problems seem similar, I wasn't able to find a reduction that works.

Comment: Have you tried concatenating u and v in the reduction? Another possibility is reducing from the QSAT2 problem.

Comment: Yes, I have tried doing the reduction by concatenating $u$ and $v$ but it doesn't seem to work. What reduction do you think is possible from QSAT2?